# NewMasterDetailForm is not working with setVisible(true)

Tags: java, swing

I've two jFrame `main.java` and `NewMasterDetailForm.java`. Using following code I'm trying to open the `NewMasterDetailForm.java`, but it is not opening -

```
NewMasterDetailForm call= new NewMasterDetailForm();
call.setVisible(true);
```

I'd also tried

```
new NewMasterDetailForm().setVisible(true)
```

I've put above code into a button and the complete code is as follows

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
NewMasterDetailForm call= new NewMasterDetailForm();
call.setVisible(true);       

    }
```

I have created NewMasterDetailForm.java using the in-built feature in IDE NetBeans which has generated the entire script itself. It main consist of connectivity information with MySQL and fetches details from it.
**NewMasterDetailForm.java contains following code**

```
package yc;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.Beans;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Raam
 */
public class NewMasterDetailForm extends JPanel {

    public NewMasterDetailForm() {
        initComponents();
        if (!Beans.isDesignTime()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("yello_cab?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNullPU").createEntityManager();
        query = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT y FROM YcTable y");
        list = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections.observableList(query.getResultList());
        masterScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        masterTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        FormListener formListener = new FormListener();

        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, list, masterTable);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${bookId}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Book Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${cuName}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Cu Name");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${mobile}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Mobile");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${noPersons}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("No Persons");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${email}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Email");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${gender}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Gender");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${cabType}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Cab Type");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${PPoint}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("PPoint");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${DPoint}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("DPoint");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${PTime}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("PTime");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${PDate}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("PDate");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${riderType}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Rider Type");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${paymentMode}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Payment Mode");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);

        masterScrollPane.setViewportView(masterTable);

        jButton1.setText("Close");
        jButton1.addActionListener(formListener);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/yc/yc.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 2, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Contact 24x7 ");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("1800-1100-MEGHA");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 804, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();
    }

    // Code for dispatching events from components to event handlers.

    private class FormListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
        FormListener() {}
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getSource() == jButton1) {
                NewMasterDetailForm.this.jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new main().setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);

    }                                        




    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private java.util.List<yc.YcTable> list;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane masterScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTable masterTable;
    private javax.persistence.Query query;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewMasterDetailForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewMasterDetailForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewMasterDetailForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewMasterDetailForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(new NewMasterDetailForm());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I am sorry, but you should be respectful to others on StackOver. In fact, I am sure you have never worked with NewMasterDetailForm and jFrame.

Comment: I've never worked with `NewMasterDetailForm`, because you've never shown it to us, `JFrame`, now, I've worked with that for 16+ years, since Java 1.3, but of course, wth respect, if you don't want our help, that is, of course, entirely your choice

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong judgment. Well, now I've updated the question.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Note that if you are dealing with multiple frames, this will turn out to be a 'show stopper'..  `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: `new main().setVisible(true);`  I am surprised that even compiled.  You have a class called `main`?

Comment: @Andrew `main` is no keyword in Java. It is just the name of a method which is used as entry point. It would even be possible to have a class `main` with a method `main` in it (`new main().main()`), although no one will do that.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke  *"It is just the name of a method.."*  Not a method in that code, it isn't.  (There is a `main(String[])` method, but no `main()` method.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `NewMasterDetailForm` is a `JPanel`, you need to wrap it in some kind of window, like a `JFrame`, similarly to the last portion of the classes `main` method, for example

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane(new NewMasterDetailForm());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @user1803551 Typing on phone

Comment: O.K., fixed it for you :)